# Passing a URL to a specific piece of example code which extracts samples from a WAV file

Tags: c, audio, wav

I don't know if it is legal on SOF to access such a specific question, but here I go:

I've found this wonderful [piece of code](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6047075&postcount=7) which takes all the samples from a WAV file and passes it into an array.

The code compiles, but I can't seem to figure out where to pass the argument of where the file is and what its name is.

Any help?

PS If this code does what it says it does, I think it could be useful to a lot of people.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code it's reading from `stdin` (and it even says in the description above the code: *"It reads from stdin"*). Evidently it's designed to be used as a command line tool (or "filter") which can be piped with other tools, or standalone using I/O redirection.

Comment: Sounds good! Any simple way to do that? I just would like to see it run :)

Comment: Just build the code as e.g. `read_wav` and then run it on the command line with input from a .wav file, e.g. `$ read_wav < my_sound.wav`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pipe output from wget or curl.

`wget -O - http://www.whatever.com/somefile.wav | yourpieceofcode`

Comment: Is this assuming that I am in the same directory as the executable?