# Getting input to an executable via stdin?

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, stdin

I have an executable that I need to take input from a .wav file on my desktop. The executable expects input on stdin.

Let us use the example:

```
/Users/tomcruise/Desktop/executable   

/Users/tomcruise/Desktop/music.wav
```

I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: This is not really a programming question and you've already been given two examples of how to do this in response to your previous question: [Passing a URL to a specific piece of example code which extracts samples from a WAV file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946916/passing-a-url-to-a-specific-piece-of-example-code-which-extracts-samples-from-a-w)

Comment: @ Paul R. I just thought it would be better to specify this detail in a new question, especially since the last one was more about that specific piece of code. No one searching for the above answer would have found it in the previous thread. Likewise, I could have been possibly a bit more patient in getting my response from the original query. My apologies. What is the protocol for a proper reaction to a negative voting? In other words, what should I now do about this blemish on my reputation? :)

Comment: @Eric: (a) it's not a programming question (belongs on http://superuser.com) and (b) you already had all the information you needed from the previous question (see comments below the answers you were given).

Comment: @Eric: you have now accepted an answer which isn't even correct (not really the answerer's fault - the question is unclear) - you should probably fix this otherwise someone else reading this question will be misled.

Comment: @Paul. Sorry about all the confusion. And thanks for putting in all the effort :)

Comment: @Eric: no problem - I'll edit your question to make it a little clearer - good luck with whatever it is that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal and do the following:

```
$ cd /Users/tomcruise/Desktop
$ ./executable < music.wav
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't it be ./executable. I think you missed out on the ./

Comment: Thanks, yes, it depends on your `PATH`, that would be better in the general case - I've updated the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your question? `stdin` is not the same as command line arguments. The latter is a file descriptor that is available to the program on startup. The latter are a bunch of strings available as strings. Running

```
/Users/tomcruise/Desktop/executable /Users/tomcruise/Desktop/music.wav
```

will "give" the `music.wav` filename to your executable which you can process.

Comment: His executable takes input from stdin

Answer (score 0):

If your executable is taking from command line arguments, it would be:

`/Users/tomcruise/Desktop/executable /Users/tomcruise/Desktop/music.wav`

If it is taking from stdin, it would be:

`/Users/tomcruise/Desktop/executable < /Users/tomcruise/Desktop/music.wav`

Answer (score 0):

You write the argument just after the filename:

```
cd /Users/tomcruise/Desktop
./executable music.wav
```

Comment: His executable takes input from stdin